# Strange behaviour in Android listview when loading images with asynctask

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I hope anyone can help me with the ListView problem I got.I have been slamming my head against a iron wall yesterday because i could not figure out what the problem was. It's not originally my project which makes it even harder.

I got a listview where I wanna load rows of contacts in. On the left side of each row I wanna (Down)load an Image async. For this i am using the following ArrayAdapter and ListItem layout, please ignore the deprecated functions.

Here is a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMqI9_y3pag&feature=youtu.be

**PROBLEM:**
Whenever the list loads all the images get loaded over each other and after that beeing placed in the correct spot. It looks really glitchy and even though it responds quick and all it looks horrible. I added a counter in my arrayadapter to count the times getView gets called.

- 4 items Without Async Images - Approx. 38 Times
- 4 items With Async Images - Approx. 180 Times

Hopefully someone can help me!

**ArrayAdapter**

```
    public class ChatContactListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatContact>{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ChatContact> chatContacts;

    public static DiskImageLoaderHelper diskImageLoader;

    public int count = 0;

    public ChatContactListArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ChatContact> chatContacts) {
        super(context, resource, chatContacts);

        this.chatContacts = chatContacts;
        this.context = context;
        diskImageLoader = new DiskImageLoaderHelper(context, "ChatListImages", (1024 * 1024 * 10), CompressFormat.JPEG, 90);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        count++;
        Log.e(DebugHelper.TAG_DEBUG, "Count: " + count + " Position: " + position);
        ChatContact chatContact = chatContacts.get(position);

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_contact_list_row, null);
        }

        ImageView contactImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);
        if (chatContact.Picture != null) {
            BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorker = new BitmapWorkerTask(contactImageView, diskImageLoader);
            bitmapWorker.execute(chatContact.Picture);
        } else {
            contactImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        TextView fromTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fromName);
        fromTextView.setText(chatContact.Name);

        Boolean l_blToMe = false;
        if (chatContact.From == chatContact.Id) {
            l_blToMe = true;
        }

        LinearLayout chatContactRow = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.chatContactRow);
        ImageView imageViewStatusMessage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastMessageStatusImg);

        TextView lastMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastMessage);
        if (CommonUtilities.isNullOrEmpty(chatContact.Message) && !CommonUtilities.isNullOrEmpty(chatContact.MessageId)) {
            lastMessage.setText("<afbeelding>");
        } else {
            lastMessage.setText(chatContact.Message);
        }

        imageViewStatusMessage.setImageResource(0);

        if (!CommonUtilities.isNullOrEmpty(chatContact.Received)) {
            imageViewStatusMessage.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chat_double_check));
            chatContactRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F2F2F2"));
            lastMessage.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        } else if (!CommonUtilities.isNullOrEmpty(chatContact.Sent) && !l_blToMe) {
            imageViewStatusMessage.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chat_single_check));
            chatContactRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F2F2F2"));
            lastMessage.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        } else if (!CommonUtilities.isNullOrEmpty(chatContact.Sent) && l_blToMe) {
            imageViewStatusMessage.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chat_arrow));
            chatContactRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F4E0CC"));
            lastMessage.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        } else {
            imageViewStatusMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        TextView receivedDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.receivedDate);

        if (!CommonUtilities.isNullOrEmpty(chatContact.Sent) && CommonUtilities.isNullOrEmpty(chatContact.Received)) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat l_dbDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                Date l_dOrgDate = (Date) l_dbDateFormatter.parse(chatContact.Sent);
                SimpleDateFormat l_showDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

                String newDateStr = l_showDateFormatter.format(l_dOrgDate);
                receivedDate.setText(newDateStr);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e(DebugHelper.TAG_ERROR, "ChatContactListAdapter::" + e.toString());
//              ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(e);
            }
        } else if (!CommonUtilities.isNullOrEmpty(chatContact.Received)) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat l_dbDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                Date l_dOrgDate = (Date) l_dbDateFormatter.parse(chatContact.Received);
                SimpleDateFormat l_showDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

                String newDateStr = l_showDateFormatter.format(l_dOrgDate);
                receivedDate.setText(newDateStr);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e(DebugHelper.TAG_ERROR, "ChatContactListAdapter::" + e.toString());
//              ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(e);
            }
        } else {
            receivedDate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        count = 0;
        super.clear();
    }

    class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {

        private final WeakReference<ImageView> contactImageView;
        private DiskImageLoaderHelper diskImageLoader;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView, DiskImageLoaderHelper diskImageLoader) {
            this.contactImageView = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
            this.diskImageLoader = diskImageLoader;
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
            String imageUrl = params[0];
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            if (!diskImageLoader.containsKey(CommonUtilities.filePathToCacheKey(imageUrl, false)) || false) {
                bitmap = CommonUtilities.getCroppedBitmap(CommonUtilities.createBitmapFromImageLocation(CommonUtilities.mStrBasePath + imageUrl), 50);
                if(bitmap != null) {
                    diskImageLoader.put(CommonUtilities.filePathToCacheKey(imageUrl, true), bitmap);
                }
            } else {
                bitmap = diskImageLoader.getBitmap(CommonUtilities.filePathToCacheKey(imageUrl, false));
            }

            return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {
            ImageView view = contactImageView.get();
            if (view != null && drawable != null) {
                view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
//              contactImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                view.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_round_overlay_grey));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ListViewItem Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_contact_list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/chatContactRow" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_image"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_round_overlay_grey"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TextualHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:baselineAligned="false">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fromName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                android:textColor="#222222"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/receivedDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                android:textColor="#777777"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/statusMessageHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lastMessageStatusImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lastMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#777777"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OnCreate in my sherlockFragment**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        mLvContactList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listContacts);
        if(mDbDataBase == null)
            mDbDataBase = nl.w3s.hulpverlener.JohelpenApplication.mDbDataBase;
        if(mCurDB == null)
            mCurDB = nl.w3s.hulpverlener.JohelpenApplication.mCurDB;

        mCursor = mCurDB.query(mTblChatContacts.mTable, mDbDataBase.dbFieldsToString(mTblChatContacts.mFields), null, null, null, null, null);
        chatContacts = CommonUtilities.getContactsFromCursor(mCursor);
        mCursor.close();

        chatContactArrayAdapter = new ChatContactListArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.chat_contact_list_row, chatContacts);
        mLvContactList.setAdapter(chatContactArrayAdapter);

        mLvContactList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            final View view, int position, long id) {

                        ChatContact chatContact = (ChatContact) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        ChatFragment chatFragment = new ChatFragment(chatContact.Id);
                        mMainObject.switchContent(chatFragment, true);
                    }
                });

        getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon_ab_chat);
        getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        MainActivity.mMenuLayout = -1;
        getSherlockActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        setStatusMessage();

        mMainObject.setTitle(mTitle);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually main problem is you didn't add **else condition statement** in most of your `if` condition statements in `getView()` method of custom adapter.

Like,

1. put `else` here

   ```
   if (chatContact.Picture != null) {
           BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorker = new BitmapWorkerTask(contactImageView, diskImageLoader);
           bitmapWorker.execute(chatContact.Picture);
   }
   else
   {
           contactImageView.setImageResource(R.id.icon); // only for your reference.. add default image
   }
   ```
2. Add `else` statement in your all `if-else if` statement for list item row views. Either make them gone in visibility or assign blank text or default images.

**Update:** As I doubt this scenario because of reference view of list row.

remove this code,

```
 View view = convertView;

 if (view == null) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_contact_list_row, null);
 }
```

Just use,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_contact_list_row, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just updated my ArrayAdapter and will put an edit version in my question. Unfortunatly this didnt solve the behaviour i am getting! I do get a littlebit less calls then before!

Comment: it actually works! I got 52 calls for my get view and the images get loaded without any strange behaviour! thanks!

Comment: hi @user370305 I found this solve my problem too, I already upvoted question and answer, I use this code the listView less smooth than before. How to make it smooth?
notice Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter: Should use View Holder pattern (use recycled view passed into this method as the second parameter) for smoother scrolling less... 
When implementing a view Adapter, you should avoid unconditionally inflating a new layout; if an available item is passed in for reuse, you should try to use that one instead. This helps make for example ListView scrolling much smoother.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent several hours trying to figure out why this was happening for my list view when I was asynchronously loading images for each row. It turns out that the list view has to have "match_parent" for the width and height set in the XML. Truly strange and weird bug.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked flawlessly. Have you figured it out why this happens with layout width set to wrap content?